# ASP.NET GridView parameter default value to empty string

Tags: asp.net, visual-web-developer

I have been struggling with this:

I have a GridView with this data source:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Sprava_SubjektuConnectionString1 %>"
SelectCommand="SELECT [Jméno], [E_mail], [Adresa] FROM [view1] WHERE ([Jméno] LIKE '%' + @Jméno + '%')">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox1" Name="Jméno" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
            </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

My desire is that when the TextBox1 is empty I get output I would get from:

```
SELECT [Jméno], [E_mail], [Adresa] FROM [view1] WHERE [Jméno] LIKE '%%'
```

But it works exactly the opposite way. Would anyone please help me with this?

Comment: What do you mean "opposite way"?  What do you expect vs. what's happening?

Comment: I get empty output and I want all-records output if the TextBox1 is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way, if your RDBMS supports ISNULL() is:

```
SELECT [Jméno], [E_mail], [Adresa] FROM [view1] WHERE ([Jméno] LIKE '%' + ISNULL(@Jméno, '') + '%')
```

Comment: Doesn't work either... Perphaps, isn't there a predefined behavior that GridView/DataSource stays empty until all the parameters are set?

Comment: Oh, right, your data source has a property called CancelSelectOnNullArgument. Good thinking.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is:

```
SELECT
  [Jméno], [E_mail], [Adresa]
FROM
  [view1]
WHERE ([Jméno] LIKE '%' + @Jméno + '%' OR @Jméno IS NULL)
```

GridView, by default, changes empty string to NULL before sending it to the DB server.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this technique:

```
...WHERE ((@Jméno is null) OR (Jméno like '%' + @Jméno + '%'))
```